# writing java Cache Manager with Search functionality

Tags: java

I want to create a cache module, which can store data coming from different tables. I also require search on these data.

Cache needs to store below kind of data in either map/list, and then search has to happen on country and capacity.

```
public class CumulativeCapacity {

private  String region;
private  String country;
private  int capacity;
private  int storeSum;
}
```

The search functionality is like, we have to check objects country is in the list [US, CAN, UK etc..] and capacity withing range1 and range2

as of now i created simple Cache Manager which is having list/map of these objects, and i am planning to use predicate to do the search.

any better logic using plain java classes?

Answer (score 1):

1: You could use cache open source libraries.

2: If you need to write yourself, some of my idea:

- Hash based container is better than others, as they are fast. Performance is cache’s only value.
- Concurrency is a large concern in cache module, you could use classes in java.util.concurrent.

Comment: Continuing to the above, need a mechanism for cache refresh to avoid data becoming stale

Comment: @hakish: agreed. and evict strategy.